# Admob issue - "Ads Disguised as Content - Must fix"

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, admob

I have a policy violation that says "Ads Disguised as Content - Must fix", I am not really sure why I am seeing this.

I have native advanced, interstitial, and appOpen admob ads in the app.

The native advanced were designed to follow the recycler view item design and after seeing this policy violation message, I have removed the ad unit.

The interstitial is placed in between a view transition at the click of a button

The appOpen on opening the app, alternate times

Has anyone here found a similar issue or know more about this violation of the policy? Any suggestions?

Comment: Questions about store policies are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: dang, didn't know about this!

Comment: Are you fix this error?

Comment: ummm, not exactly, @MuhammadAsad. I removed AppOpen ads and the violation was lifted, haven't got a chance to see what was wrong with it.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? If you don't mind please give some details Thanks @MuhammadAsad